# Spring cloud stream routing on payload

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I want to use spring cloud stream for my microservice to handle event from kafka.

I read from one topic that can hold several JSON payloads (I have one topic since its all messages arrived to it are from the same subject).
I have different cloud function to handle according to the different payload.

How can I rout the incoming event to specific function based on property in its payload?

Say I have JSON message that can have the following properties:

```
{
  "type":"A"
  "content": xyz
}
```

So the input message can have a property A or B

Say I want to call some bean function when the type is A and another bean function when type is B

Comment: Have you tried writing a method of `Function<KStream`, then calling `KStream.branch` method? https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.0.M1/reference/html/index.html#_multiple_output_bindings

Comment: I don't need to write to send to different topic I want to call function ( process the event from kafka ) based on the property in its payload

Comment: Then have you tried to use `.filter()` to do checks against this property, then `.map()` function to pass those filtered events over to the functions you want to run?

Comment: I see...Thanx. But say I have 3 or 4 possible value for this property how can I handle or route according to it?

Comment: I assume something like this `KStream kstream1 = input.filter((k, v) -> v.prop == 1).map(...); KStream kstream2 = input.filter(k, v), v.prop == 2).map(...);` ... "Route" implies you have outgoing records to new topics, though, which would mean you use `.branch`, and you can have consumers for those topics that call your other processing methods instead

Comment: I see..Than. What I want to do is to call spring cloud function based on the incoming payload property and not to rout it to different topic. I guess I didn't know to express is in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from the question whether you are using the message channel-based Kafka binder or Kafka Streams binder. The comments above imply some reference to `KStream`. Assuming that you are using the message channel-based Kafka binder, you have the option of using the message routing feature in Spring Cloud Stream. The basic usage is explained in this section of the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_event_routing

You can provide a `routing-expression` which is a SpEL expression to pass the right property values.

If you want advanced routing capabilities beyond what can be expressed through a SpEL expression, you can also implement a custom `MessageRoutingCallback`. See this sample application for more details: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/routing-samples/message-routing-callback

Comment: How can I bind the routing function to particular topic name? or all the traffic from all topics go through the   functionRouter?

Comment: If you want the routing function to consume from a specific topic do this: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.functionRouter-in-0.destination: <your-topic-name>`

Comment: Thanx. By the way I follow you example and it seems that I alaea get byte [] as payload in Message when implementing MessageRoutingCallback. Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure why, maybe the default serializers. Compare with the sample app, it converts into the proper type in the corresponding functions. You might need to debug it. If you can provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then we might be able to look at that and troubleshoot.